# how to get jquery ajax status code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to know that how can we get ajax status code in jquery.
I have this ajax block:

```
$.ajax{
    type: "GET",
    url: "keyword_mapping.html",
    data:"ajax=yes&sf="+status_flag,

    success: callback.success,
    complete: rollup_filters(),
    failure: function(){
        alert("Failure");
    }
    }
```

Now in above code, in case of failure, how can i get ajax status code and some description of that status code ??

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to use the [`error`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) option to capture this. For example:

```
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    // Your handler here...
}
```

You can then use the `jqXHR` object to retrieve information about the failure.

[From the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR):

> For backward compatibility with XMLHttpRequest, a jqXHR object will expose the following properties and methods:
>
> - readyState
> - status
> - statusText
> - responseXML and/or responseText when the underlying request responded with xml and/or  text, respectively
> - setRequestHeader(name, value) which departs from the standard by replacing the old value with the new one rather than concatenating the new value to the old one
> - getAllResponseHeaders()
> - getResponseHeader()
> - abort()

Answer (score 3):

First, you have a few syntax errors. The above is a method call, so it needs to follow `$.ajax({ ... });` (with parenthesis).

Secondly, you want to supply the **error** property as part of the object, not failure ([see docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more information).

Third, when you do bind to an error, you are supplied three parameters: jqHXR, textState, errorThrow. These arguments will supply you the details of a failed AJAX call. (More specifically, try `jqXHR.status`)

Alternatively, you can bind to the [`$.ajaxError`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) function as well.

---

**Update** To keep this more up-to-date, you should now be following the [`Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) API (as of jQuery 1.5), which would make binding to an error look something like the following:

```
$.ajax({ /* options */ })
  .done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ){
    // here you bind to a successful execution.
  .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
    // Here you can catch if something went wrong with the AJAX call.
  })
  .always(function(){
    // here you can execute code after both (or either) of
    // the above callbacks have executed.
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your failure callback to

```
error:function (xhr, options, error){
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(error);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like `failure` in ajax settings. Replace failure by error and you get 3 arguments in the error callback. First argument is the xhr object which has a status property in it.

```
$.ajax{
    type: "GET",
    url: "keyword_mapping.html",
    data:"ajax=yes&sf="+status_flag,

    success: callback.success;
    complete: rollup_filters(),
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
         alert(jqXHR.status);
    }
    }
```